# Extracting headings from PDF in Java

Tags: java, pdf

How can I extract a list of headings out of a PDF in Java?

I am trying to extract the contents and structure from a PDF file. I have tried using Apache Tika and PDFBox to get the contents in plain text and html, but I cannot figure out how to get the headings.

Comment: Unless you have so called tagged PDFs with proper tagging of headings, those headings essentially merely are normal text. You might try and develop some heuristics (larger size, special fints, ...) but using them amounts to educated guesswork.

Comment: No I don't know. Are you really interested in my knowledge level (that **is** what you are asking about)? Should you not rather ask "How can I extract a list of headings out of a PDF in Java"?

Comment: @anyone Sorry, I am new to this site. Thanks for the advice, I will keep that in mind for future questions.